# Load PPT File using Third Party Android Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[ScreenShot of the app after lauching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3658.jpg)I have imported this library https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android in my app by adding the .jar file in the libs folder.I want to load ppt files into my app.Unfortunately, the app keeps showing the loading spinner after launching.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.itsrts.pptviewer.PPTViewer;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

PPTViewer pptViewer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pptViewer = (PPTViewer) findViewById(R.id.pptviewer);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/Download/check.ppt";
    pptViewer.setNext_img(R.drawable.next).setPrev_img(R.drawable.prev)
            .setSettings_img(R.drawable.settings)
            .setZoomin_img(R.drawable.zoomin)
            .setZoomout_img(R.drawable.zoomout);
    pptViewer.loadPPT(this, path);

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">

<com.itsrts.pptviewer.PPTViewer
    android:id="@+id/pptviewer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: did you find any solution ??

Comment: @Sunil Chaudhary, nope:(

Answer (score 1):

PPT viewer code is running but it only has fullscreen issue.
The reason why it is showing running is due to the ppt path you are providing is incorrect . If path provided is incorrect it keeps on loading.
Try checking if path provided is correct

```
File file = new File("Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
        + "/Download/check.ppt"");
if(file.exists()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Present",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Not Present",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

if file not present or path is wrong it will show toast notification